# How to Flatten a Dictionary in a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I would like to flatten a dictionary that is inside the dataframe.
Below is my data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID': [0,1],
        'Name': ['Lucas', 'Benjamin'],
        'Records': [{'Date':'2022-05-19', 'TimeIn': '7:00', 'TimeOut': '15:00'},
                    {'Date':'2022-05-19', 'TimeIn': '8:00', 'TimeOut': '14:00'}]}
sample = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want my output to be:

```
ID  Name      Date          TimeIn    TimeOut
0   Lucas     2022-05-19    7:00      15:00
1   Benjamin  2022-05-19    8:00      14:00
```

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
pd.concat([df.drop(columns="Records"), pd.DataFrame(df["Records"].tolist())], axis=1)
```